# How do I remove the border for the table headers?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c|}

    & 1 & 2 & 3  \\ 
    \hline
    1 & x & x & x \\ \hline
    2 & x & x & x \\ \hline
    3 & x & x & x \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want the blue, where the row headers and column headers are separated from the table. I tried removing a `\hline`, but this didn't give me what I wanted.

I know theres other questions like this one, but they have more complicated code and just want to know the basic steps so I can use it later.

Thanks

Comment: \cline{2-4} for the horizontal lines and \multicolumn{1}{c}{your text here}  for the vertical lines.

Comment: How can I evenly spread it out? The `\multicolumn`? Please see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `\multicolumn{1}{c}` and `\cline`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    1 & x & x & x \\
    \cline{2-4}
    2 & x & x & x \\
    \cline{2-4}
    3 & x & x & x \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Would like to know how to evenly spread out the multicolumn so the 1,2,3 are in the center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c|}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\qquad 1 \quad 2 \quad 3} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    1 & x & x & x \\
    \cline{2-4}
    2 & x & x & x \\
    \cline{2-4}
    3 & x & x & x \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use for the first line `&\multicolumn{1}{c}{1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{3}\\\`

Comment: Possible to get the output by using `nicematrix` package...